# Регулярное выражение (валидация строки лога Apache)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строка

```
96.154.64.194 - [17/Sep/2015:10:17:30 +0000] "GET /?utm_source=gl&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=kok HTTP/1.1" ["uid=210FDE53A08FF955138C3C6502030303" : "-"] - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"
```

Мне надо провалидировать ее (это правильный пример строки). Я использую следующее регулярное выражение

```
[0-9.]* - \[(.*?)\] "(.*)" \["[a-zA-Z0-9=-]*" : "[a-zA-Z0-9=-]*"\] - "(.*)" "(.*)
```

Но если я попытаюсь вставить такую строку

```
96.154.64.194 - [17/Sep/2015:10:17:30 +0000] "GET /?utm_source=gl&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=kok HTTP/1.1" ["uid=210FDE53A08FF955138C3C6502030303" : "-"] - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"91.154.64.194 - [17/Sep/2015:10:10:33 +0000] "GET /e.gif?chto_smotrish? HTTP/1.1" ["uid=210FDE53A08FF955138C3C6502030303" : "-"] - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"
```

Он признает ее валидной. Какое выраженеи мне лучше составить? (Это запись логов и nginx). Последовательность такая

```
remote_addr - [time] "query" ["uid" : "uid"] - "referrer" "user_agent"
```

---

Обе строки в одном блоке кода, чтобы их можно было синхронно скроллить и сравнивать:

```
96.154.64.194 - [17/Sep/2015:10:17:30 +0000] "GET /?utm_source=gl&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=kok HTTP/1.1" ["uid=210FDE53A08FF955138C3C6502030303" : "-"] - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"
96.154.64.194 - [17/Sep/2015:10:17:30 +0000] "GET /?utm_source=gl&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=kok HTTP/1.1" ["uid=210FDE53A08FF955138C3C6502030303" : "-"] - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"91.154.64.194 - [17/Sep/2015:10:10:33 +0000] "GET /e.gif?chto_smotrish? HTTP/1.1" ["uid=210FDE53A08FF955138C3C6502030303" : "-"] - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"
```

Comment: вы не забыли метасимволы начала и конца строки (`^` `$`)?

Comment: @Etki не поможет, т.к. последняя часть все захватит, надо немного регулярку поменять, например, группы вида `"(.*)"` заменить на `"([^"]*)"` или использовать ленивые квантификатры `"(.*?)"`

Comment: @user3551959, а чем вас не устраивает вторая строка? Там же просто слились две строки в одну и данные можно получить по обеим?

Comment: @BOPOH, `*?` всё равно захватит, если там другого способа нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, что захватит? Строки всегда будут такими, т.е. открывающая кавычка означает наличие закрывающей, а значит и захватываться будет до закрывающей (в grep'е по крайней мере так)

Comment: @Qwertiy, а, понял, если с концом строки имели ввиду? Тогда да - захватит все, я без конца смотрел

Comment: @BOPOH, я имел в виду захватит, если дописать в конец знак `$`. Т. е. во варианте `... ".*?"$` под `.*?` всё равно попадёт весь лишний хвост строки.

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно проверить, что строка соответствует формату и выделить из нее все блоки, то подойдет такое регулярное выражение

```
/^([\d.]+)\s-\s\[([^\]]+)\]\s"([^"]+)"\s\["([\w=-]+)"\s:\s"([\w=-]+)"\]\s-\s"([^"]+)"\s"([^"]+)"$/
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/wL3nC2/1

Если нужно просто проверить строку на соответствие, то такое

```
/^[\d.]+\s-\s\[[^\]]+\]\s"[^"]+"\s\["[\w=-]+"\s:\s"[\w=-]+"\]\s-\s"[^"]+"\s"[^"]+"$/
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/bN1nY7/1

Answer (score 0):

```
var ip = '[0-9.:]+',
    time = '\\[[^\\]]+\\]',
    STR_IN_QUOTS = '"(?:(?:\\\\")|[^"])*"',
    query = STR_IN_QUOTS,
    uid = STR_IN_QUOTS,
    referrer = STR_IN_QUOTS,
    userAgent = STR_IN_QUOTS;

var re = RegExp(`^(${ip}) - (${time}) (${query}) \\[(${uid}) : (${uid})\\] - (${referrer}) (${userAgent})$`, 'i');
```

Проверка:

```
[
'96.154.64.194 - [17/Sep/2015:10:17:30 +0000] "GET /?utm_source=gl&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=kok HTTP/1.1" ["uid=210FDE53A08FF955138C3C6502030303" : "-"] - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"',
'96.154.64.194 - [17/Sep/2015:10:17:30 +0000] "GET /?utm_source=gl&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=kok HTTP/1.1" ["uid=210FDE53A08FF955138C3C6502030303" : "-"] - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"91.154.64.194 - [17/Sep/2015:10:10:33 +0000] "GET /e.gif?chto_smotrish? HTTP/1.1" ["uid=210FDE53A08FF955138C3C6502030303" : "-"] - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"'
].map(function(s) { return s.match(re) })
// [Array[8], null]
```